# Opencart 1.5 проблема с $text_compare в header.tpl

Tags: php, opencart, header

Проблема заключается в том что я вывел в **header.tpl** значение переменных (**$compare и $text_compare**)взятых с контроллера и шаблона страницы категорий(**Catigory.tpl**). На страницах категорий сслыка($compare) и текст($text_compare) в **header** видны как надо, а на  на главной странице сайта и остальных (регистрация, home, etc...) ссылка рабочая а текст пишется название переменной(text_compare), а не ее значение, почему не берется значение?

вот изображение со страниц сайта:
    на картинку при клике мы попадем на страницу сравнения, а вот переменная **$text_compare** пишется так 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот изображение со страниц категорий category.tpl
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Все проблему решил сам. Совсем забыл про каталог LANGUAGE!